# show alert dialog in flutter without onTap, onPressed etc

Tags: flutter, flutter-alertdialog

How do I display an alert dialog in flutter without user interaction?

I have a Widget that shows a `ListView`. When a specific condition is true, I want to display an alert dialog within the same widget (everything is a widget in Flutter, right?). So no user interaction is needed.

this is the build method of my widget:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
final providerData = ref.watch(someProvider);
//showAlertDialog(context);
final anotherProviderData = ref.watch(anotherProvider);

return anotherProviderData.when(
  data: (entries) {
    return CustomScrollView(...
```

I want to display an `AlertDialog` based upon the provider data.

Comment: Do you have any mockup?

Answer (score 1):

You can call `showDialog` from a function you call based upon your trigger.

```
showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return MyAlertDialog();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do it:

```
Future(() {
        showAlertDialog(context);
      });
```

`showAlertDialog(context)` is the method showing the alert dialog.